# Ear Deployment in Jboss AS 7 failure with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, jboss7.x, maven-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

I am migrating an existing project to AS7. My Ear Structure is below, Guys some one please help the structure is correct or not. Because I am getting ClassNotFoundException when I am deploying, I think I have placed jar in wrong place.

```
Ear
  webmodule.war
  Ejbmodule.jar
```

When I extract ear.

```
META_INF
       |-> maven
                |-> com.myapp.mss
                |-> ear
                    pom.properties
                    pom.xml
       application.xml
       Manifest.mf
one.jar
two.jar
three.jar
My-ejb-module.jar
My-web-module.war
```

Whether lib folder is necessary for JBoss EAP 7 ?

I am using maven for build.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                <generateClient>false</generateClient>
                <jarName>myappejb-${env}-${pom.version}</jarName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <finalName>myapp-${env}-${pom.version}</finalName>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.myapp.mss</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webModule</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/myapp</contextRoot>
                        <bundleFileName>mssweb-${env}-${pom.version}.war</bundleFileName>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Deployable files are placed in the root directory of your EAR. Dependency JARs should be placed in the lib directory in your EAR. You can override the lib directory with a custom value by using the library-directory tag within your EARs deployment descriptor.

Documentation of the library-directory tag from the XSD:

> The library-directory element specifies the pathname
>               of a directory within the application package, relative
>               to the top level of the application package.  All files
>               named "*.jar" in this directory must be made available
>               in the class path of all components included in this
>               application package.  If this element isn't specified,
>               the directory named "lib" is searched.  An empty element
>               may be used to disable searching.

Comment: Whether I can keep deployable files as well as dependency jar in the root directory. Is it possible? For me ClassNotFoundException is coming in my deployable jar not in dependency jars

Comment: You should be able by using the library-directory element as mentioned above. But the question is... why? This will slow down deployment, since all the JARs must be scanned for annotations. I would recommend to use the default EAR structure until you have a very good reason to do it differently.